# Some web services questions

Tags: c#, web-services

I have some Web Service Questions.

I work with VS2005, and I need to build a web service.

1. Can I copy/move/delete files or folders from a web service?
2. Can I can make (or use) an SDF Database file from a web service?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

A webservice is just code executing on the server, it can do anything the user it's running as has permissions to do